# Postfix install fails. MySQL conflict

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I'm using CentOS 6, and trying to create a virtual mirror on a new server of an old one (which someone else setup).  As much as possible, I want keep everything with the same version, but I've started from scratch and am documenting everything.  By default, yum would install MySQL 5.1.73.  I downloaded MySQL community v5.1.69 and installed it manually.  This required installing a "shared compatibility" package of MySQL v5.1.69 first, and removing mysql-libs.x86_64.  With that in place, I successfully mirrored MySQL.

Now, I'm trying to install Postfix.  Yum wants to pull version 2.6.6-6.  This fails because it requires a dependency that it attempts to install as well: mysql-libs.x86_64 v.5.1.73-5.  It splits out a pile of errors messages which are all similar to this:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-community-5.1.69-1.rhel5.x86_64
```

My old server is using postfix v2.6.6-2, which is apparently compatible with MySQL v5.1.69.  I found the rpm for that version of postfix.  It doesn't install, because it requires mysql-libs.  I can't install mysql-libs v.5.1.69, because it conflicts with the MySQL community edition (also 5.1.69) that I installed.  I tried to install the MySQL 5.1.73 "shared compatibility" package, but that conflicts with MySQL community too.

I'm going in circles.  Is the only way to break this chain to uninstall MySQL community? Must I just use the v5.1.73 default, and the Postfix 2.6.6-6?  I don't expect any real problems, but I'm going to end up with slightly different versions of MySQL and Postfix then I am trying hard to mirror.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, uninstalled all the MySQL community packages, and just installed the out of the box yum MySQL and Postfix.  That works, but I now have different versions of this software on these two servers as a result.